# System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session bringing another user session

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, session-variables

we have a website hosted in IIS. we are storing currently logged in user details in session["user"]. if i login with user id E1001 ID then session["user"] contains E1001.  But when multiple users are connected to the application and when i refresh the page , instead of getting currently logged in user E1001 i am getting other logged in user like E1002.

How to stop getting the other logged in session?

Comment: this is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using different browsers.

Session variables stores users data and commit it to a cookie in the browser, if you login to the application with another user in the same browser, a second cookie (with new user data) will overlap the first one. So refreshing the first tab you should be using the second cookie.

I hope I have left myself understand. 
Greetings.